# Using Headers with Google Community Connector

Tags: google-apps-script, restful-authentication, looker-studio, request-headers

How would you use authorization headers when writing a Google Community Connector?

eg. When calling the URL in getData() would it be something as simple as this:

var response = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp."https://api_example.com", {
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
        "host": *********,
        "key": ************}
)).root.station;

I am continuously getting a data connection error in Google Data Studio but I can't be sure if it is because of poor authorisation such as above or if I have improperly formatted by getData().

Comment: It looks like a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be required to provide a suggestion to this question, such as code attempts, etc so that fellow users have a starting point of reference upon which to build from

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `KEY` authtype is supported: https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/reference#authtype